# Simple, no frills ,get LAT/LON in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, cllocation

I just want to display the lat/lon on the screen of an iPhone.

I've read a half dozen examples, and everyone decides to do 3 other cool things at the same time and soon I am in over my head.

I would love a link to an example of plain vanilla (not kitchen sink like Apple's LocateMe) example of where I need to set up the CLLocation object, how do I turn it on, put lat/lon in a variable, and then turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link with how to build an app that does nothing but display your lat/long: [Lat/Long Display App](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application)